# How do I use normal textboxes to create a text editor in visual basic code?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am currently trying to create a text editor in visual basic windows forms. I am using a toolstrip with file(new, open, save, save as, exit), edit(copy, cut, paste), and help(about)

I am trying to get the toolstrip to actually do all those things,

What I am trying to do is get those things to work with NORMAL textboxes and not rich textboxes.

I've got no problem getting these things to work with rich textboxes.

```
Dim dialog as NewOpenFileDialog
Dim file as string
dialog.ShowDialog()
file = Dialog.FileName
Dim sr as New StreamReadere(file)
Dim RichTextbox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd
sr.close()
```

The above code is for the open one that is what I use to click the file >> open but it only accepts rtf files.

So my question is how do I do the open files with normal textboxes so I can open ANY files.

Comment: The code you already have will work fine to display the contents of a plain text file in a `TextBox`. Of course, if you expect to see multiple lines of text in the control then you must have set `Multiline` to `True`. *"it only accepts rtf files"*. An `OpenFileDialog` will allow you select any file you want. If yours only allows RTF files to be selected then it is because you have configured it that way. The obvious solution is then to NOT configure it that way.

Comment: Actually, the code you posted wouldn't even compile so it must only be an approximation of the actual code you were using. I'm going to make the assumption that `Dim dialog as NewOpenFileDialog` was actually `Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog` and `Dim RichTextbox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd` was actually `RichTextbox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd`. It does help to post the actual code you want help with though. Who knows how many other inaccuracies there are in what you posted.